# Call function in other files by using globals()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to using `globals` to call the function whose name matches the string. For example:

```
def abc():
    print('test')

globals()['abc']()  # -> test
```

but if `abc` is in another file, how should I call this function.

```
import file_that_have_abc as imp
globals()['imp.abc']()
```

will not work because it will call function name 'imp.abc' in recent file instead.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do here? If you `import somefile` and `somefile.abc` exists then `getattr(somefile, 'abc')` would give you access to it, but without context this could be a http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 2):

Use `getattr` for accessing members of the module:

```
func = getattr(globals()['file_that_have_abc'], 'abc')
func()
```

of course, you can drop the `globals` here if you don't *need* to look up the module too.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `globals()` call to access the variables in your current module. For other modules, just use the name you imported the module with - and to retrieve functions/classes/variables from there from their names as strings, use the  `getattr` function.

For example:

```
import math
func = `sin`

getattr(math, func)(0)
```